# Google Cloud Functions, Timeout 5 Secs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

In Google Actions, how to increase the request timeout?

When I call my external API through Google Actions, Google Actions will only wait for 5 seconds (max)for the response from my API. But my API is taking more than 5 seconds to respond, which leads to error

> "Malformed Response: final_response must be set"

and

> "XXX isn't responding right now. Try again soon."

*(Google Assistant -> Google Actions(returns response in 5 Sec at most(**need to configure this**)) -> DialogFlow -> Cloud Functions(can wait till 9 mins) -> External API(taking more than 20 seconds to respond))*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please learn how to ask a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The timeout in your Cloud Function can be edited at any time.  It defaults to 1 minute, and [can be extended up to 9 minutes](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec). 

As for the other part, could you edit your question to make it more clear?

Comment: @Mangu thanks for your response. Please check my updated question.

Comment: Here is the answer: Using followUpEvent, i am able to increase the timeout to one minute or more.

Comment: can you please tell me how to do it? isn't dialowflow webhook timeout 5 second?

Answer (score 2):

Finally I came through a workaround to increase the Google Device response time. Using **followUpEvents** in dialogFlow API, waiting time increased to one minute.

Comment: Hey @Simarpreet, could you please tell me how exactly you did it? I have the same problem. I'm using DialogFlow UI (not any API) to manage my intents, but for my fulfilments I have a webhook to Firebase Functions.